# android downloaded images are not in correct format

Tags: android, android-imageview, outputstream

I'm downloading some images from my webservice using the below code and it works perfectly fine but after they are downloaded and copied to sd card, they are unknown file types although they have .jpg at the end and my application still can load them into imageviews but I can't open any of those downloaded images via the device's gallery from file manager. Any idea?

Here's how I download and save the images:

```
public void downloadImage(String url, String fileName) {
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        String[] fileNameSplit = fileName.split("\\.");
        String fileNameMobile = fileNameSplit[0] + "-mob." + fileNameSplit[1];

        URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = urlConnection.openConnection();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        File outFile = new File(file.getPath() + "/" + fileNameMobile);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        copyFile(in, out);
        out.close();
        in.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

example file name in directory browsed by file manager:

```
_58df8aa6dbb44ff7b870b49a4b2d8efb-mob.jpg
```

Comment: care to explain the down vote??

Comment: Did you add the ".jpg" extension to the filename?

Comment: @BlackMagic Yup, it's there. The application can load the images into imageviews but by using the file manager they are unknown files though they have .jpg at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outStream);
```

Here's little example

```
File file = new File(file.getPath() + "/" + fileNameMobile);
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems after I read the downloaded file name from the url, there's a `\n` is added to end of the code which resulted into making that file unknown and also I couldn't read the file later on using the same file name without `\n` but now by removing that `\n` from the end of the filename it works fine now.